# The “silicon power” sd card 4ggb class 10 memory card is compatible with raspberi pi?

Tags: linux, compatibility, raspberry-pi, sd-card, sdhc

Today I bought a memory card "Silicon Power" SDHC 4ggb, class 10and I need to know, this memory card is compatible with raspberry pi B or not ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your card is not listed on the Embedded Linux Wiki's [list of compatible SD cards](http://elinux.org/RPi_SD_cards) for the Raspberry Pi. Two other cards from this manufacturer are listed as not compatible, so the odds are that you may experience problems.